# Why my antd form is not validating good after i add `type: number` in rules?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I'm trying to make validation form using Antd Design Form, but when I add `type: 'number'` error message is not hiding and I can't submit my form. When I remove `'type: 'number'` everything is working fine. Any idea how to fix that?

```
  <Form.Item
    name='userToken'
    label='User Token'
    rules={[
      validateForm,
      {
        type: 'number',
        len: 5,
        message: 'User Token must be 5 numbers long!'
      }
    ]}
  >
    <Input />
  </Form.Item>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: If your value is type `number`, then use `<InputNumber` component instead of simple `<Input` component

Answer (score 0):

As Muhammad said you should use [InputNumber](https://ant.design/components/input-number) instead of just using simple Input.

The reason why your form is not beeing validated is because simple Input returns a string value but your form is checking if provided value is a number so validation will fail.

You can take a look [here](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-nest-messages) in this example